# How can I prioritize wireless networks with network-manager

Tags: wireless, network-manager, networking, connection, settings

Mostly I use my laptop in an environment where different wireless networks are available and I would like to preferably connect to one of those and only fall back to the other one if that one is not available.

Is there any way of prioritizing which wireless networks network-manager preferably connects to? The only workaround I found so far was unchecking *Connect Automatically* in the options and re-enabling it when my preferred network is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible

However, there is a brainstorm idea which describes what you want:

http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/6906/